# Json Result with DataAnnotations on Model in WebApi

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am using ASP.NET WebApi , while sending result to JSON , is it possible to send Data Annotations on Model - ModelMetadata
for example DisplayName attribute, ShowInEdit , ShowInDispplay and other custom attributes  along with  Fieldnmae and value.

```
public class Role
    {
        public Role()
        {
            Users = new List<User>();
        }

        [ScafoldingColumn(false)]
        public int RoleId { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Role Name")]
        [Required]
        [ShowForDisplay(true)]
        [ShowForEdit(true)]
        public string RoleName { get; set; }

        [ShowForDisplay(true)]
        public ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
    }
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Could you provide your C# class and an example of what you want ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON as a file format doesn't support data annotations. The best solution for that, which I've seen so far, is to have meta actions. Those meta actions can return the data-annotations as an additional json-object. You can afterwards also cache those data in the local storage on the client or similar, so you don't need to download them, every time the user accesses a page.